# java array elements memory consistency

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

A very naive array based circular buffer implementation,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SomeRingBuffer {

    private volatile String[] holder;
    private AtomicInteger cursor = new AtomicInteger(-1);

    public SomeRingBuffer(int capacity) {
        holder = new String[capacity];
    }

    public void add(String data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return; // do nothing
        }

        int updatedCursor = cursor.updateAndGet(i -> (i + 1) % holder.length);
        holder[updatedCursor] = data;
        holder = holder; // holder is marked volatile, intentional write barrier
    }

    public List<String> getLastN(int n) {
        if (n < 1 || n > holder.length) {
            n = holder.length;
        }

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(n);
        int current = cursor.get();

        while (n > 0) {
            result.add(holder[current--]);
            if (current < 0) {
                current = holder.length - 1;
            }

            n--;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

It is supposed to be non-blocking and thread safe. Synchronisation is achieved using `AtomicInteger`, while memory visibility is ensured via `volatile` r/w.

Is there any problem from concurrency point of view? As we are writing to array elements, is memory visibility here guaranteed among the threads?

Comment: No. Because reading `holder` doesn't guarantee which slots of the array are safe to read afterwards.

Comment: @akarnokd as ```holder``` is marked volatile, won't reading it trigger read - barrier? and hence fetching latest of all array slots?

Comment: Also `cursor` is written before the store so you might find a slot just about to be written as null.

Comment: Unrelated volatile. Ideally you'd have to read/write the array slot itself as volatile, i.e., via VarHandle, or have before and after cursors protecting the slot.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into JCTools queues, and even using them instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks - as I mentioned, its not a production piece of code, some toy example for understanding the concepts

Comment: One race condition is when the `cursor` is incremented but the array slot is not yet written, then the reader side thinks it can now read at `cursor` but the slot is still null.

Comment: If you swapped the array assignment and the cursor update, now you have `data`, that may not yet gotten fully initialized, accessible from `getLastN` as the flush from the barrier didn't happen yet and you read all elements from the buffer.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks for your comments. As you pointed out, I agree that synchronisation is broken because cursor is written before the store, not as a single atomic operation. One last question - assuming method ```getLastN``` is called after method ```add```, will the other thread see the latest of the slot value (on the basis of volatile read of parent store array reference)? Or am I wrong in expecting fetch of  volatile ```holder``` reference, to have an impact on children slots memory visibility? Let's say ```AtomicIntegerArray``` class doesn't exist for a moment.

Comment: If there is only one call to `add` and `holder` write already happened, `getLastN` will see the array slot properly written and the object itself properly published.

Comment: However, if there is any overlapping between `add` and `getLastN`, all bets are off.

Comment: Assuming that a statement like `holder = holder;` had an effect, is just wrong. A `volatile` write establishes a happens before relationship to *subsequent* reads but since all reads see the same value (as the reference doesn’t change), there is no way to tell whether a read is subsequent. The other thread could read the array reference before the writing threat performed the redundant write, hence, there is no happens before relationship.

Comment: @Holger Sorry didn't get what you mean by ```holder = holder;``` has no effect. Do you mean it won't trigger write barrier? Yes, you are right that if there is any overlap between the ```add``` and ```getLastN``` methods, then the outcome is unpredictable.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “write barrier” in the specification. Hence, you can not assume that this statement that has no observable effect will “trigger write barrier”. There are JVMs using barriers as an implementation detail, still, even in those implementations, you need a pair of write barrier and read barrier in the right *synchronization order* to establish memory visibility. So even on those JVMs, a construct that can’t guaranty that the actions will happen in the right order does not establish the necessary *happens-before* relationship.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there are following problems:

1. update in `add()` is not atomic
   This was already discussed in the comments by @akarnokd and you: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72743294/java-array-elements-memory-consistency#comment128488006_72743294), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72743294/java-array-elements-memory-consistency#comment128488294_72743294)
   But I would like to show one more example:

   - given:

     - buffer size is 10
     - 50 threads executing `add()`
     - 1 thread executing `getLastN()`
   - all 50 `add()`-threads simultaneously finished incrementing `cursor` and are writing now in `holder[idx]`

   As a result for every element of the `holder` there are 5 parallel writes by different threads without synchronization (i.e. data races).
   The elements returned by `getLastN()` can be any random combination of old and newly written values.
2. `getLastN()` is not atomic
   While you are iterating over the elements of `holder` in one thread, other threads might update the buffer at the same time.
   As a result the elements returned by `getLastN()` might be from "different generations".
   This cannot happen in a single-threaded code — so this might be considered as non-thread-safe as well.
   (sometimes such "inconsistencies" are considered acceptable in concurrent algorithms, but then this should be explicitly documented)

Comment: thanks for taking time to write this detailed analysis. Yes, if thread contention is much higher and appropriate buffer capacity is not chosen at the time of ```SomeRingBuffer``` object construction, the issue you highlighted is bound to happen. A trade off between memory usage and concurrency level. As I mentioned above, this is not at all a production code, something just for education purposes.